# Why is this Google OAuth callback failing only the first time a user logs in my site?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

So I have a website where users can log in with Google. The code below checks if the user has already logged in before. If they have, they just get logged in to the site but when they haven't, they are first added to a Mongo database then logged in.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,    
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async function(request:any, accessToken:any, refreshToken:any, profile:any, done:Function) {
    let details = {
        name: profile.given_name,
        provider: profile.provider,
        googleID: profile.id,
        email: profile.email,
        picture: profile.photos[0].value
    }
    const user = new User(details)
    let query = User.find({googleID: profile.id}).select('-bookmarks -firstLogIn -lastLoggedIn -__v')
    let result = await query.exec().then(async (res:any, err:Error) => {
        if(err)
            return done(err, null);
        if(!res.length) {
            res = await user.save()
            .then((r:any, e:Error) => {
                return r
            }).catch((e:Error) => {
                return done(e, null);
            })
        }
        return res
    });
    return done(null, result[0]);
}));
```

This works when the user has already logged in to the site before but when they first attempt to log in, they are instead redirected to the failureRedirect URL in the code below.

```
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate("google",{
        failureMessage: "Cannot login to Google",
        failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login/error",
        successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login/success"
    }))
```

localhost:3000 is the React side of the project.

Also in case this happens again, how do I go about debugging these kinds of things?

Answer (score 0):

You are using async/await with then/catch. If you use async/await use try/catch with it as it make the code sync. You might try this refactor.

```
try {
let result = await query.exec();
if(!result.length) {
     result = await user.save();
     return result;
}

return done(null, result[0]);

} catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
     return done(e, null);
}
```

Now, Your catch can log the error and you can debug it easily.